# Android studio Resources: Chinese Traditional or Chinese Simplified?

Tags: android, android-studio

According to the google Translate Docs: Chinese (Simplified) is "zh-CN". and Chinese (Traditional) is "zh-TW".

But when I created a strings.xml resource file for chinese, it only worked for "zh":

[image]

Should I use simplified or traditional strings for my chinese strings.xml file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create `values` for specific regions as follows,

Right click on values folder and choose New > Android resource directory to bring up the following popup. Type `zh` to show the required locale.

[image: Resource]

This will create `values-zh-rCN` and `values-zh-rTW` as follows,

[image: Folders]

Answer (score 4):

If your min SDK is 24 (7.0), then you can use the the improved resource resolution described in the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support#postN).

Use `values-b+zh+Hant` for traditional Chinese and `values-b+zh+Hans` for simplified Chinese. You will see that zh_TW, zh_HK and zh_MO get traditional, all other regions get simplified.